# Qt4.8 QGraphicsWidget usage

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I can't figure out from the docs, how to use QGraphicsWidget to draw something on it.

Can you help me please? I try this code but when I add it to the graphics scene it shows nothing.

```
class Platform : public QGraphicsWidget
{

    public:
        Platform()
        {

            QGraphicsEllipseItem elipse(0,0,10,10,this);
            setGraphicsItem(&elipse);

        }

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QGraphicsWidget` is not a widget on which you draw things, it is a widget that can be draw in the Graphics View framework. To draw things, you'll need a [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html) to hold the items to draw and a [`QGraphicsView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html), which is the widget that displays the `QGraphicsScene`.

You should start with the [documentation for the Graphics View framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html).

Comment: Yes, I know about QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView. I created instances of QGraphicsItem and added them the the scene and showed the scene with the view. I shall add QGraphicsItems to the Gr-Widged, right?

Comment: The QGraphicsWidget is a QGraphicsItem with layouting logic. If you just want to place some QGraphicsItems, there is usually no need for QGraphicsWidgets at all.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky what I need is to have some graphics which can send signals. Is gr-widget ok for these purpose?

Comment: @Kolyunya it depends on what you need exactly. QGraphicsWidgets are okay if you want some real widget, but in a a QGraphicsScene. If you just want to be able to do something when an item is clicked/dragged/used in any way, it might be simpler to subclass a QGraphicsItem (or any subclass that is closer to what you want), and override its protected methods.

Comment: @Kolyunya: If signals is what you need, don't subclass `QGraphicsWidget`, but its superclass `QGraphicsObject`.